# @react-native-community/datetimepicker does not work with ios 14

Tags: react-native, expo, datetimepicker

Not sure if there is another way around this but `react-native-datetimepicker` is not working with iOs 14. There are a number of threads that discuss solutions for non expo-managed packages (ie: creating a AppDelegate file or changing the "display" to default to "spinner") but neither of these are working/ I am able to do because I am building with managed expo.

The last effort was to upgrade the package to the latest version, 3.0.6, but when I run `npm install @react-native-community/datetimepicker`, nothing changes. I am stuck on version 2.2.2. My terminal states the package is "up to date", even though we know it is not. I have also tried manually updating the package by typing in the correct version and clearing out my package-lock, node modules, and refreshing the cache.

I cannot upgrade my Xcode version to higher then 11.7 which was my last possible solution.

I have deleted my package-lock and node modules and cleared cache and reinstalled and still no luck.

Is there another package or another way around this bug with iOs 14 and datetime picker?

```
  Expo CLI 3.28.2 environment info:
System:
  OS: macOS 10.15.4
  Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
  Node: 15.0.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
  Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
  npm: 7.0.3 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms: iOS 13.7, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.4, watchOS 6.2
IDEs:
  Xcode: 11.7/11E801a - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
  expo: ^37.0.12 => 37.0.12 
  react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
  react-dom: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
  react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz => 0.61.4 
  react-native-web: ^0.11.7 => 0.11.7 
  react-navigation: ^3.13.0 => 3.13.0 
npmGlobalPackages:
  expo-cli: 3.28.2
Expo Workflow: managed
```

Comment: This kind of thing is so incredibly frustrating and is completely absent when using Flutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to upgrade my expo and react native to be able to install the newer version of datetimepicker

I am now on:

```
Expo CLI 4.0.4 environment info:
System:
  OS: macOS 11.0.1
  Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node: 15.3.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
  Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
  npm: 7.0.14 - /usr/local/bin/npm
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms: iOS 14.2, DriverKit 20.0, macOS 11.0, tvOS 14.2, watchOS 7.1
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 4.1 AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283
  Xcode: 12.2/12B45b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
  expo: ^39.0.0 => 39.0.5 
  react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
  react-dom: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
  react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.3.tar.gz => 0.63.2 
  react-navigation: ^3.13.0 => 3.13.0 
npmGlobalPackages:
  expo-cli: 4.0.4
Expo Workflow: managed
```